# Call a function from one PHP file to another

Tags: php, javascript

I am not quite sure why have I not been able to call a function from say File1 to File2 . I have used the require_once also .

Eg :

```
File1.php

<?php
function Test()
{
alert("Hello");
}
?>

File2

<?php
require_once("File1.php");

My code 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

My code....

$("#email_summary").click(function() {
     <?php    
     Test();   
     ?>                            
});
</script>
```

Could you please let me know my mistake ? 
Thanks guys :)

Comment: you are calling php function in javascript. add <?php test(); ?>

Comment: PHP is server side and javascript is client side. You can't directly call a PHP function from javascript.

Comment: You mix different language. You cant call `Test()` only call it at a client side.

Comment: You cannot mix call by client side's click. what you want to do in php's function Test?

Answer (score 3):

you can not call php function by JavaScript  like you did

```
$("#email_summary").click(function() {

     Test();                               
});
</script>
```

should be

```
$("#email_summary").click(function() {

    <?php echo Test();   ?>
});
</script>
```

and

```
function Test()
{
return 'alert("Hello")';
}
```

---

**edit:**  if you want to make it work like your code you can do this by

File1.php

```
<?php function Test() { ?>

    alert("Hello");

<?php } ?>
```

and than just include like

```
<?php    
    Test();   
 ?>
```

Comment: @Justin sorry you need echo  too

Comment: This will never work, How are you mixing server side function with client side language.

Comment: It worked fine . What if I add echo instead of alert ? will it work ?

Comment: @Justin for discussion come to php chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: I meant instead of alert("Hello")  I replace it by echo ("Hello") will it work ? will the echo statement work inside javascript ??

Comment: @Justin No, it won't work. Because you're writing JavaScript and not PHP, you have to write document.write("Hello") or console.log("Hello") depending on where you want the output.

Comment: @Justin Try to learn PHP and JavaScript separately, choose one, learn it and learn it well. Then continue with the other. You'll gain on that in the end, like now it's like trying to learn french and spanish simultaneosly, that's not a very good idea, you'll only confuse different best practices in the different languages.

Comment: @sakjur well he is just including code by server side ... and op does know what this code will do .. also its not wrong

Comment: @NullPointer I know what he's doing, but he was also considering using echo instead of the alert (as far as I could understand), considering echo isn't even in JavaScript, that is not very good coding - it won't work.

Regarding including client side code by server side, that's not very good practice. It'll help you in the long run to separate server-side and client-side :)

Comment: @sakjur  well tell me whats difference `function one(){return "one";} echo one();` and `function one(){echo "one";}  one();`

Comment: @NullPointer I think he asked if `function f(){return 'echo "hello";'};` would work. And AFAIK, that won't work.